# Bash: how to pass array items as options?

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to generate headers for curl based on an array:

```
HEADERS=( "content-type: text/plain" "Authorization:  password" )
```

When I specify each one manually, it works:

```
curl --header  "${HEADERS[0]}"  --header  "${HEADERS[1]}" http://httpbin.org/headers
```

but when I try to generate automatically, curl complains:

```
curl `for H in "${HEADERS[@]}";do echo --header $H ;done` http://httpbin.org/headers
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: text
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: password
...
```

I've tried various quote escapes and evals with no luck.  Can you suggest a way to make it work?

Comment: BTW, it would be better form for your `HEADERS` variable to be in lowercase (or, at least, to have at least one lowercase letter), since it's neither an environment variable or a builtin. Following this convention prevents overwriting variables in either of the aforementioned special classes unintentionally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple and concise solution, without loops:

```
HEADERS=( "content-type: text/plain" "Authorization:  password" )
curl "${HEADERS[@]/#/-H}" http://httpbin.org/headers
```

The substitution expression is performed independently on each array element, with the result being inserted as one word per array element (the same as `"${HEADERS[@]}"`). The `#` in the pattern means "only replace at the beginning. Writing the command-line option using `-H` instead of `--header` makes it much easier to add the option name to each string, since curl accepts `-Hoption_value`, whereas the normal command line syntax `--header=option_value` syntax is not accepted by curl. (Thanks to @wfr for pointing out that curl won't accept `--header=...`.)

Comment: Nice; much simpler than the loop approach.

Comment: curl doesn't understand --key=value.
It's a valid approach for programs that do, of course.

Comment: @wfr: Interesting and annoying. I fixed the answer by changing it to generate `-Hheader: value`, which curl's option-parser is ok with.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

```
parameters=()
for((i=0; i<${#HEADERS[@]}; i++)); do
    parameters+=("--header" "${HEADERS[$i]}");
done
curl "${parameters[@]}"
```

See also:

- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays

Comment: or possibly `for header in "${HEADERS[@]}"; parameters+=("--header" "$header"); done` ?

Comment: Yes, that's valid and concise.

Answer (score 0):

I liked wfr's answer but to avoid creating an intermediate variable, I came up with:

```
for H in "${HEADERS[@]}"; do [[ "$HEADERS" == "-"* ]] || HEADERS=(); HEADERS+=("-H" "$H");done
curl "${HEADERS[@]}" http://httpbin.org/headers
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is probably better to actually use the intermediate variable instead of calling out to test :|

Comment: @AXE-Labs, I agree that using the intermediate variable is the cleaner solution -- but that said, `[[ ]]` is actually built-in syntax, so it's not incurring the kind of overhead that an external call does. (Actually, on modern bash, even `[` / `test` is available as a builtin, so `/bin/test` isn't invoked unless one goes out of their way).

Comment: BTW, you could set `HEADERS=()` without `export`ing it; exporting a variable to the environment is not a well-defined operation for arrays, and you certainly don't need to do so here.